# What is better: to delete pointer or set it with a new value?

Tags: c++, pointers

simple question in c++ , say i have a loop and i have function that returns pointer to item
so i have to define inner loop pointer so my question is what to do with the pointer inside the   loop , delete it ? or to set it with new value is good
for example:

```
for(int i =0;i<count();i++)
{

 ptrTmp* ptr = getItemPtr();
 // do somthing with the ptr ...
 // what to do here ? to delete the poinetr or not? 
 delete ptr;  // ??

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It totally depends on what the interface `getItemPtr` specifies. Usually a "get pointer" interface that returns a raw pointer isn't trasnfering ownership of the pointed-to object so it would be a mistake to delete it. In this case you can safely let the pointer variable go out of scope. There is no need to set it to `NULL`.

On the otherhand, `getItemPtr` might be documented as returning a pointer to a new object which must be deleted, in this case you would need to delete it but a better way to ensure this happens would be to use a smart pointer to ensure that this happens. In your example initializing a `std::auto_ptr` would be the simplest and most portable way to do this.

```
std::auto_ptr<ptrTmp> ptr( getItemPtr() );
```

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what `getItemPtr()` does.

What says the documentation ?

If it says the caller is responsible for the object destruction, which is often the case, then you **have to** to delete it before the pointer goes out of scope (or before its value is lost).

Usually, when a function returns a pointer and says you're responsible for it's deletion, there is an opposite function (something like `deletePointer(PointedType* pointer)`) whose role is to delete the allocated memory. Because, unless otherwise specified, you cannot assume that the pointed value was allocated using `new` and thus can't know for sure if you must call `delete`, `delete[]`or `free()`.

You may as well set the pointer to `NULL` after its deletion, to avoid future reuse; that's a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Writing `delete ptr;`, actually destroys the *pointee*. If you don't want to destroy it, simply leave the *pointer* going out of the scope.

Setting the *pointer* to a new value will have no effect on the *pointee*.